# Impossible to configure Selenium + Cntlm proxy in Python?

Tags: firefox, selenium, proxy

Is it impossible for people behind authenticate proxy (with domain) to use Selenium in Python, going through CNTML proxy on localhost?

Nothing seems to be working. Eventhough I put proxy settings to that:

```
myProxy = "localhost:3128"

proxy = Proxy({
            'proxyType': ProxyType.MANUAL,
            'httpProxy': myProxy,
            'ftpProxy': myProxy,
            'sslProxy': myProxy,
            'noProxy': '' # set this value as desired
})

self.browser = webdriver.Firefox(proxy=proxy)
```

I also tried to create a custom profile for Firefox, configuring the CNTLM proxy inside it, forcing in python that profile for my Firefox webdriver, but nothing is working.

Is that even possible?